# Using element().offset() in AngularJS E2E test

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e

I am writing an end-to-end test in Angular, and I would like to verify the position of a DOM element in relation to another DOM element. Fortunately, the Angular E2E DSL has a passthrough method for jQuery's offset() method. Perfect for my use case!

However, I'm confused how to use the object that this method returns. The call to offset() returns an object with the properties **top** and **left**. When I try to access these properties in the test, Angular complains.

This code works great:

```
expect(element("#anID").offset()).toEqual({"top":100,"left":100});
```

This code doesn't work, and throws an error:

```
expect(element("#anID").offset().top).toEqual(100);

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.angular.scenario.matcher.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8000/test/angular/angular-scenario.js:23994:41)
    at Object.executeStatement (http://localhost:8000/test/angular/angular-scenario.js:23960:30)
    at Object.chain.(anonymous function) [as toEqual] (http://localhost:8000/test/angular/angular-scenario.js:23968:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/test/E2E-scenarios.js:78:53)
```

How do I use the return from offset() to construct an expectation roughly like:

```
expect(element("#anID").scrollTop() - element("#anotherID").offset().top).toEqual(100);
```

---

### Update

After the back and forth with Josh David Miller, I see my real question is: how can I get the value of an angular.scenario.Future object outside of an expect() call, so I can use it as the basis of other expectations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer on the [Angular mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/FszMlvnrQfY). Something like this will work for using multiple angular.scenario.Future object values in a single expectation:

```
  it('async expectation', function() {
    browser().navigateTo('index.html');
    var relativeElement = element("#anID").prop( 'offsetTop' )

    this.addFuture('ScenarioRunner step title', function(done) {
      expect(element('#anotherID').scrollTop()).toEqual(relativeElement.value - 100);
      done();
    });
  });
```

There's a issue open on the [angular github repo](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/429) for integrating this into the ScenarioRunner more elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

You actually shouldn't need the jQuery passthrough. This should work just fine:

```js
expect( element.prop( 'offsetLeft' ) ).toEqual( 361 );
expect( element.prop( 'offsetTop' ) ).toEqual( 451 );
```

If it doesn't, can you post a full minimal example on jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: yes, that does the trick for accessing that offset value. There's still an issue with performing the subtraction operation, since the element() call returns a future, not a primitive value.

Comment: @SteveGoodman Why are you using jQuery-style selectors to access your DOM elements? Can you provide more code?

Comment: Is there another way in angular e2e tests to find the position of an element?

Comment: What I meant was that I assume your HTML comes from one or more directives, which you $compile in your E2E test. So don't you already have a reference to the element(s) and all their children?

Comment: I'm not making any $compile calls, perhaps that's my trouble. The test code is not much more than what's in the question, plus a call to browser().navigateTo() and input().enter(). Here's a fiddle of my directive and html: http://jsfiddle.net/ZScFA/

Comment: It's hard to tell without everything together ... But you don't need any of that jQuery as you can get all of that info with angular. Here's what I'm talking about with E2E compilation: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/test/tooltipSpec.js

Comment: the linked tests aren't E2E tests, they're unit tests. I'm using the higher level framework described in http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing

Comment: Sorry about that - my bad. But it doesn't actually change anything I said. I'm trying to piece together what you have from bits and pieces here and there, but it's pretty difficult. Can you at least *link* to your full code?